# How To Make Text Fade And Go Up

Tags: javascript

How do I make a div, with a specific id, fade and go up?
Here is some psuedo-code:

```
y=400
opacity=0

while (y > 100) {
document.getElementById('text').style.position = y
document.getElementById('text').style.opacity = opacity

y--
opacity-=0.01
}
```

Comment: I would actually use css to handle the animations because you should let the native implementation do the hard work (it's faster too). [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) is a good reference. You could also use something like [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) if you want to use a css framework.

Comment: Could you please give an example of css animation? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look  [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)   




For more detail  
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

Comment: Do you just want an element to fade up and go out once the page loads or when an action happens like on a button click?

Comment: On button click would be helpful thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment

> I would actually use css to handle the animations because you should let the native implementation do the hard work (it's faster too). CSS-Tricks is a good reference. You could also use something like animate.css if you want to use a css framework.

edited snippet: see below

Here you go. Using [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). Simple enough?

Remove `infinite` for non infinite. Check out the [animate css github for more info](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)

---

Animate.css is a css framework, meaning they give you css stylesheets that you can apply by adding classes. Under the hood, animate.css uses css keyframes. Check out the source (the css implementation) for `fadeOutUp` [here](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/source/fading_exits/fadeOutUp.css).

---

From your comment:

> How would I make the text animate when I click a button?

Add an [EventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) on click to add the classes using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Examples)

(edited snippet again)

---

> Quick question, how do I make it so the button will work more than once? Because right now you can only click it once and then it won't work anymore.

Add an EventListener for when the animation ends then remove the classes from the element.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h1 class="thing-to-fade">Animate.css</h1>
<button id="my-button">Fade Out Up</button>
<script>
    const element = document.querySelector('.thing-to-fade'); // define the element
    document.querySelector('#my-button').addEventListener('click', event => {
        element.classList.add('animated',  'fadeOutUp');
    });
    
    // add an eventlistener for the 'animationend' event
    element.addEventListener('animationend', event => {
        // after the animation ends, these classes will be removed
        element.classList.remove('animated',  'fadeOutUp');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How would I make the text animate when I click a button?

Comment: check the updated answer. please consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: Quick question, how do I make it so the button will work more than once? Because right now you can only click it once and then it won't work anymore.

Comment: there you go. hope it helps. try to understand the browser's [document object model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and javascript as a whole. it help you progress as an applications developer

Comment: Thanks for the help!